# Addthis : Different url's for image and on image link click

Tags: html, addthis

I am trying to use Addthis widget for my website.Right now I am using the following code to share image to different website.

```
<script>var addthis_config = {     
services_overlay:'facebook,twitter,email,more'
}</script>
```

```
<div class='giveTopMargin'>
   <a href='link' class='lightbox'  title='title'>
      <img class='addthis_shareable' src='img_url' addthis:url='img_url' addthis:title='message' />
   </a>
</div>
```

What I want is that when the user clicks the share button for facebook.I need the image preview of the `img_url` I've mentioned and when this link is successfully shared on facebook I need whoever clicks on this post on facebook, he should be redirected to the main page of my website instead redirecting him to the `img_url`.

Right now the problem with this code is that it shows me the following share box.
[image]

As you can see it is showing me the `img_url` in the title and description instead of the things I've mentioned above that is the `title message`.If I change the `img_url` to the main page of my site then this will not show me the preview of the image I've shared.

I hope I am clear enough. Please let me know for any clearification.

Code Source : http://www.addthis.com/labs/photo-sharing#.USyj-jAyZjY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to solve the problem so I sent an email to the `Addthis support` and they said that facebook tries to catch the image preview from the url we mention.So I was not able to accomplish this using the `Addthis Plugin`.

So I end Up doing it myself by using the [facebook.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) dialog to share with the settings I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is change the value for addthis:url, so for example, if the site you want them to go to is http://www.supportmyidea.com, then your img tag should look like:

```
<div class='giveTopMargin'>
    <a href='link' class='lightbox'  title='title'>
        <img class='addthis_shareable' 
             src='[your_image_url]' 
             addthis:url='http://www.supportmyidea.com' 
             addthis:title='Support My Idea' />
    </a>
</div>
```

The image preview that Facebook shows is actually based on the URL you specify.  Facebook scrapes that page and will show an image from the page - if you specify an og:image tag, Facebook will use that image.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: but this gives the preview of the image present on that url not the image which is shared

Comment: Unfortunately, that is how Facebook works - they scrape the page of the URL the user is going to.  Facebook is trying to give users a preview of the page they are going to.

Comment: But they have given an open hand when we use the `open graph api` in which we can specify the redirect_uri and preview image seperately.I end up using the API.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use their format.  Make your own image and url using an `img` tag and an `a` tag.  All the URL has to be is this :

```
http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?url={url}
```